# Tensorflow memory issue using add

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am basically trying to recursively update a tensor object of dimension (1,batch_size) in a for loop in my tensorflow script. For example:

```
def __cost( self, trueX, trueY, reuse ):

    x = tf.expand_dims( trueX, 0 )
    X = tf.tile( x, [self.config['L'],1,1] )

    # X -> A
    A, mu_phi1, ls_phi1 = self.build_nn_gauss( x, self.config['sizeq_x2a'],
                          self.config['dim_a'], self.config['L'], 'phi1', reuse )
    _cost = -tf.reduce_sum( ls_phi1, -1 )

    # AX -> G (this is the semiclassifier)
    AX = tf.concat( [ A, X ], -1 )
    pre_G  = self.build_nn( AX, self.config['sizeq_ax2g'], '0phig2', reuse )
    log_pred_G = tf.layers.dense( pre_G, self.config['dim_g'], name='0phi2g', reuse=reuse )
    log_pred_G = log_pred_G - tf.reduce_logsumexp( log_pred_G, -1, keep_dims=True )
    pred_G = tf.exp( log_pred_G )


    if trueY is not None:
        # y = tf.expand_dims( trueY, 0 )
        # Y = tf.tile( y, [self.config['L'],1,1] )
        g = tf.expand_dims( trueG, 0 )
        G = tf.tile( g, [self.config['L'],1,1] )
        depth = 2

        _cost_supervised_bi_label = 0
        _cost_supervised_multi_label = tf.reduce_sum( tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits( logits=log_pred_G, labels= G), -1 )


        for i in range(self.config['dim_y']):

            y = tf.expand_dims( tf.one_hot(tf.to_int32(trueY[:,i], name='ToInt32'), depth, dtype=self.dtype ), 0 )
            Y = tf.tile( y, [self.config['L'],1,1] )

            # AGX -> Y (this is the classifier)
            AGX = tf.concat( [ A, G, X ], -1 )
            pre_Y  = self.build_nn( AGX, self.config['sizeq_agx2y'], '{}phi2'.format(i), reuse )
            log_pred_Y = tf.layers.dense( pre_Y, 2, name='{}phi2y'.format(i), reuse=reuse )
            log_pred_Y = log_pred_Y - tf.reduce_logsumexp( log_pred_Y, -1, keep_dims=True )
            pred_Y = tf.exp( log_pred_Y )

            # reuse layers if created or else create a new layer
            try:
                _cost += self.__add(_cost, self.__eval_cost_given_axgy( A, X, Y, G, True ))
            except:
                _cost += self.__add(_cost, self.__eval_cost_given_axgy( A, X, Y, G, False ))

            b = _cost 



            _cost_supervised_bi_label += -tf.reduce_sum( tf.multiply( Y, log_pred_Y ), -1 )
```

Running it like this, consumes a lot of gpu memory. I further did a test, running essentially the same thing but removing the addition operation (for example):

```
_cost = self.__add(_cost, self.__eval_cost_given_axgy( A, X, Y, G, False ))
```

and the large memory consumption stopped (the reduction in Gbs). I don't know what is wrong. Is there a different way addition and update work in tensorflow than just updating the tensor? Is there a way I need to do the update a tensor in order to avoid the memory leak?

```
 def __eval_cost_given_axgy( self, A, X, Y, G, reuse ):
    '''
    A, X, Y are 3D tensors of shape
    n_samples x batch_size x dim

    reuse -- whether to reuse NNs

    return 2D tensor of cost function
    n_samples x batch_size
    '''
    # A,G,X,Y -> Z
    AGXY = tf.concat( [A, G, X, Y], -1 )
    Z, mu_phi3, ls_phi3 = self.build_nn_gauss( AGXY, self.config['sizeq_agxy2z'],
                          self.config['dim_z'], self.config['L'], 'phi3', reuse )

    _cost = -tf.reduce_sum( ls_phi3, -1 )
    _cost += .5 * tf.reduce_sum( tf.pow( mu_phi3, 2 ), -1 )
    _cost += .5 * tf.reduce_sum( tf.exp( 2*ls_phi3 ), -1 )

    ...................

    return _cost
```

Comment: You should not be mixing python control flow to have control flow in Tensorflow. There are [specific ways](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) to loop in Tensorflow, although rarely needed. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @mikkola I am trying to add up the different components of a cost function.

Comment: I think the problem is with the add operator and not the loop.

Comment: How is `fun` implemented?

Comment: fun is a function of dense layers, it calculates and then returns the cost for each call. There is no loop in it. Just a straight run.

Comment: Does it also create those layers each time it is called? It would really help if you edit the post to include the relevant details.

Comment: @mikkola It reuses the layers. I have updated the question with the real codes sample

Comment: If your reuse logic is working properly, it could also mean that there is some other error because just a 1000 addition operations shouldn't take up several gigabytes. Maybe you are actually creating new constant tensors accidentally somewhere, or have things in your graph that should rather be fed in as placeholders. I suggest you to also plot the graph in Tensorboard to verify such things when it still works with a smaller number of iterations in your loop.

Comment: Generally using for-loops to create during graph creation is a bad idea. How many times does it loop (i.e. what is dim_y)? The problem is that all those ops you call within the loop will be created *for each iteration of the loop* which can easily blow up the graph with hundreds of copies of almost the same operation.

Comment: @xdurch0 dim_y can be any number (in our case 20). It's the dimension of a tensor Y. I want to train the model on each of the dimension of Y. Do you have a suggestion on how to avoid this issue in this situation? Is there a way to update/overwrite the values of a tensor without making a copy?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really give anything concrete because I don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve and it seems kinda complex. In principle there are two ways:
1. Use something like `tf.map_fn`. This allows you to define the operations just one and then map it over the dimensions of `y`. Should reduce memory consumption, but is still quite slow.
2. Index magic. Use things like tf.gather to collect all the dimensions you'd otherwise loop over and work on everything in parallel. I'm afraid this is hard to explain in concrete terms (and difficult to implement)...